# Topology (confusion related to subspace topology and properties of a set)

Tags: general-topology

The interior of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is given by $\operatorname{int}(A)$, defined as the union of all **open** subsets of $A$.

I am confused if they mean open with regards to the subspace topology or topology of $X$ itself.

Comment: They mean the topology of $X$. If they mean the relative topology then the definition is meaningless since the subset itself is open with respect to the relative topology.

Answer (score 1):

The interior of a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, denoted $int(A)$, is defined with respect to the topology of $X$ itself, not just the subspace topology of $A$. In other words, when we say "the union of all open subsets of $A$," we're referring to subsets that are open in $X$ and contained in $A$.

To clarify, an open subset of $A$ in this context means any subset of $A$ that is also an open set in the overarching space $X$. The interior of $A$ is the largest open set in $X$ that is contained entirely within $A$. This definition ensures that the concept of "interior" is directly tied to the topology of the whole space $X$, highlighting how properties of subsets like $A$ are understood in the context of their containing space.